# C# incrementing filename

Tags: c#, path, increment, streamwriter

I'd like to change code a little so that if I already have got a file it will write (1), (2) etc. after the file name. In the current way, it saves file, then another use of the program adds more lines to the existing file. If I get the idea how to change it, I am thinking about making the files not (1), (2), but Results_DATE_TIME (for exmaple: Results_2015_05_20_1953).

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
foreach (string filename in openFileDialog.FileNames) //number of files varies
{
    double m = Math();

    string path = desktopPath + @"\Results.txt";
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
    {
        writer.WriteLine(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just use datetime to append to your filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your path generation using the following:

```
string fileName = string.Format(@"\Results_{0}.txt", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss"));
string path = desktopPath + fileName;
```

Comment: It works, although, when the second passes it will make naother file with another second, so it will for exmpale write 200 lines and next 200 in next file.

Answer (score 0):

Try someting along the lines of

```
  path = "Results-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-ff") + ".txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

if two person add a file at same time, it will conflict anyways. In that case, I'd use guid:

```
path = += "-" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   fileName = string.Concat(@"\Results_", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss-ff"), ".txt");
    string path = desktopPath + fileName;
```